# asp.net Button onclick event not firing. instead used Link Button, onclick event is firing but page reloads itself

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net c#. I am facing a problem that a button onclick event is binding but not firing. I don't know why. Instead I used a Link Button. In Link Button onclick event is firing but page is reloaded itself. I don't know why. Any idea about this problem I'm facing?

**.aspx File**

```
  asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1_brand_image" onchange="ShowPreview(this)" runat="server"
asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server"  CssStyle="text-decoration:none;" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CausesValidation="False"
```

**.cs File:**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Profile Image  
        {  
            if (IsPostBack)  
            {  
                String product_path = Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/" + shopname.Value + "/");  
                if (!Directory.Exists(product_path))  
                {  
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(product_path);  
                }  
                String extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1_brand_image.FileName);  
                FileUpload1_brand_image.SaveAs(product_path + shopname.Value + "_profileimage" + extension);  
                Session["path"] = product_path + shopname.Value + "_profileimage" + extension;  

            }  
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnO8X.png)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net Page reload is happening because of Postback. To avoid that you need to use AJAX. AJAX requests will avoid full page reload. You can use [JQuery](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer) or [APS.net AJAX toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-cs).

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAsyncUpload" runat="server"
           Text="Async_Upload" OnClick = "Async_Upload_File" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
           OnClick = "Upload_File" />      
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnAsyncUpload"
          EventName = "Click" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnUpload" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



protected void Async_Upload_File(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Upload_File(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool hasFile = FileUpload1.HasFIle;
}
```

Comment: Actually I want image path to be inserted in database. Using jquery I cannot have image full path. That's why I am using asp.net button or linkbutton and using fileupload toolbox I can get the image

Comment: Please post some code samples. So everyone can get more insight.

Comment: View the Code please and if you know the problem tell me the solution please